# How to get the selected Item position of a customized spinner from onItemSelectedListener?

Tags: android, android-spinner, android-adapter

Check the below pic.
I guess arg2 of the overrided method is supposed to be the position of the item that I've currently selected, right? But, it's always being 0. I want the correct position to do stuffs. Any suggestion?

[image]

Here's my adapter class.

```
public class PojoSpinnerAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<Pojo> {

private Activity activty;
private ArrayList<Pojo> pojoList;
LayoutInflater inflater;

public PojoSpinnerAdapter(Activity activity, int resource,
        ArrayList<Pojo> pojoList) {
    super(activity, resource, pojoList);
    this.activty = activity;
    this.pojoList = pojoList;
    inflater = (LayoutInflater) activity
            .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
}

@Override
public View getDropDownView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    return getCustomView(position, convertView, parent);
}

@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    return getCustomView(position, convertView, parent);
}

public View getCustomView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    View row = inflater.inflate(R.layout.taxo_spinner_item, parent, false);
    Pojo pojo = pojoList.get(position);

    //.... blah blah
    return row;
} }
```

Comment: are you sure `onItemSelected()` method is called ?

Comment: of cuz, you could see in the pic, it was when I'm debugging.

Comment: And is it working fine if you do it Anonymously ?

Comment: yes., problem solved. It works. I'm just confusing. Thank you so much.

Comment: You are welcome bro, Glad to help you. May I add this as detailed answer ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suggest not to create methods like this and assign `OnItemSelectedListener()`. Simply do this either implementing this in class like here

```
public class YourClass implements AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener {}
```

and assign `this` to `Spinner`,

**OR**

Try doing it anonymously like here

```
mySpinner = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.mySpinner);

mySpinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {

        @Override
        public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1,
                int arg2, long arg3) {

             int selectedPosition = arg2; //Here is your selected position

        }

        @Override
        public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }       

    });
```

Answer (score 1):

You can also  use your getCustomView(.,.,) for this purpose

```
public View getCustomView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

    View row = inflater.inflate(R.layout.taxo_spinner_item, parent, false);
    Pojo pojo = pojoList.get(position);

    //.... blah blah
    row.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

             Toast.makeText(context," position :"+position,short).show

            }
        });

    return row;
}
```